# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.onPress.bind')

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**Gist**:  [Dashboard.js](https://gist.github.com/jackbillstrom/3d9e85931563ca9e55096c90247b3098)

I am creating an iOS application with React-Native, I get this error when my **Dashboard.js** is rendered.

My **Dashboard.js** renders different `scrollableTabView`'s which each contain a `ListView`, I have included some code from one list item below.

```
renderArchiveOrder(order) {
  return (
    <TouchableHighlight onPress={this.onPress.bind(order.id)}>
       <View style={styles.listObject}>
       <View style={styles.thumbnail}>
       <Text style={styles.title}>#{order.bid}</Text>
       <Text style={styles.time}>TID</Text>
       <Text style={styles.subTime}>{order.time}</Text>
     </View>
     <View style={styles.information}>
        <Text style={styles.restaurantName}>{title}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.dropoffName>{order.locations.dropoff.address}</Text>
     </View>
     </View>
    </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }
```

My problem is that when **Dashboard.js** is rendered, the app crashes and the included screenshot is being shown.

It clearly states that `renderArchiveOrder: Dashboard.js @ 364:0` is throwing an error, here's my `onPress` function. 
I can't understand my error is line **364**, and why my `TouchableHighlight` onPress doesn't work.

`id: index` is line **364**.

```
onPress = (index) => {
  this.props.navigator.push({
    title: 'Order',
    component: Order,
    passProps: {
      id: index
    }
  })
};
```

Why does this occur when I'm just trying to send data to a click function and push the navigator to a new view?

[image: Screenshot from view render]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're passing your `renderArchiveOrder` method as a value to another component, it loses its context. Thus, the `this` variable inside your method will *not* refer to your component instance, and trying to access `this.onPress` will yield `undefined`.

To fix this, simply bind your method to your component instance before passing it to your `ListView` component:

```
<ListView
  dataSource={this.state.archiveDataSource}
  renderRow={this.renderArchiveOrder.bind(this)}
  style={styles.listView}/>
```

Comment: Best explanation ever ! Thank's dude